# How to add users from one tenant to another in Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have created a new tenant in Azure AD. But the users are in default tenant, is there any way to add users from default tenant to newly created tenant in Azure AD.

Answer (score 1):

You can invite them to the new tenant as [guests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal). This way you can use them in both tenants with a single set of credentials and avoid exporting and importing them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would reccomend to export all users from Azure with powershell and then Import them back, I'm not sure if Azure has some migration tool ...

Comment: Can you please explain how can do that with commands

Comment: Well it's not gonna be that simple, but start with connecting to Azure with 
Connect-AzureAD
Then you can check each user with  Get-AzureADUser
But there is gonna be much more, pretty much imposible to figuree out all parameters of your enviroment just like this.

Comment: @FatalxE Please edit your answer with that info.